# Can you Map Entity Class to GraphQL Schema Types

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

So currently I am using the SDL .graphql file to define my types and queries. I would prefer to keep it that way except for all the different types I would have to define. My current entity classes are pretty big and I was wondering if there was a way to map existing Entity classes to GraphQL types, rather than manually having to declare every single entity into a type in the .graphql file.

I have seen examples of using annotations but they usually completely do without a .graphql schema file. I was wondering if there was a way to do this while still able to load the .graphql file.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you desire. You want to generate your classes based on your graphql schema?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Graphql Tools: Map entity type to graphql type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58801227/graphql-tools-map-entity-type-to-graphql-type)