# How to use graphql with jpa if schema is different to database structure

Tags: java, jpa, graphql, graphql-java

There is a given database structure and graphql schema.
Fortunately they have a lot in common but unfortunately there are some difference.
Let's say there are entities in java to match the following database structure.

SQL:

```
TABLE ANIMAL
+ID NUMBER(19)
+NR_OF_LEGS NUMBER(19)

TABLE SHEEP
+ID NUMBER
+LAST_TIME_SHEARED DATETIME
+ANIMAL_ID NUMBER(19)

TABLE COW
+MILK_IN_L NUMBER(3)
+ANIMAL_ID NUMER(19)
```

Java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ANIMAL")
public class Animal

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(name="nrOfLegs", nullable=false)
private long nrOfLegs;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "SHEEP")
public class SheepE

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(name="lastTimeSheared", nullable=false)
private Datetime lastTimeSheared;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = AnimalE.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "animalId", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)   
private Animal animal;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "COW")
public class CowE

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(name="milkInL", nullable=false)
private int milkInL;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = AnimalE.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "animalId", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)   
private Animal animal;
}
```

The existing GraphQl schema is considered to be like this:

```
type Sheep{
id: int!
lastTimeSheard: String!
nrOfLegs: int!
}

type Cow {
id: int!
milkInL: int!
nrOfLegs: int
}
```

The project uses graphql-java in version 11.0 (guess we should update soon)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
  <artifactId>graphql-java</artifactId>
  <version>11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The graphql works fine and isimplemented like this:

```
@Component
public class GraphQLProvider {
    @Autowired
    GraphQLDataFetchers graphQLDataFetchers;

    private GraphQL graphQL;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {this.graphQL = /*init;*/null;}

    private RuntimeWiring buildWiring() {
        RuntimeWiring.Builder b = RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring()
                .type(TypeRuntimeWiring.newTypeWiring("Query")
                        .dataFetcher("freightCarrier", graphQLDataFetchers.getCow()))
                .type(TypeRuntimeWiring.newTypeWiring("Query")
                        .dataFetcher("personCarrier", graphQLDataFetchers.getSheep())));
        return b.build();
    }
}

@Component
public class GraphQLDataFetchers {
@AutoWired
private CowRepository cowRepo;
@AutoWired
private sheepRepository sheepRepo;

public DataFetcher getCow() {
        DataFetcher dataFetcher = (DataFetchingEnvironment dfe) -> {
            int id = dfe.getArgument("id");
            return getGraphQlCowFromCowEntity(cowRepo.getById(id));//dirty!
        };
        return dataFetcher;
    }

public DataFetcher getCow() {
        DataFetcher dataFetcher = (DataFetchingEnvironment dfe) -> {
            int id = dfe.getArgument("id");
            return getGraphQlSheepFromSheepEntity(cowRepo.getById(id));//dirty!
        };
        return dataFetcher;
    }

private Cow getGraphQlCowFromCowEntity(CowE ce){//dirty!
  return new Cow(ce.getId(), ce.getMilkInL(),ce.getLegs());
}

private Sheep getGraphQlSheepFromSheepEntity(SheepE se){//dirty!
  return new Sheep(se.getId(), se.getLastTime(),se.getLegs());
}
```

```
public class Sheep

private long id;
private Datetime lastTimeSheared;
private int nrOfLegs;
public Sheep(long id, DateTime lasttimeSheared, int nrOfLegs){
//u know what happens here
}
}

public class Cow

private long id;
private int milkInL;
private int nrOfLegs;
public Sheep(long id, int milkInL, int nrOfLegs){
//u know what happens here
}
}
```

So how to get rid of **getGraphQlCowFromCowEntity** and **getGraphQlSheepFromSheepEntity**. It double ups the code and also is in direct conflict to what graphql is suppose to be abstraction of the data. With this design here each time all fields are loaded through jpa and not only requested fields.
Imagine this is a way more complex environment with more fields.

The graphql schema can't be changed as it's not my responsibility, changing the entire back-end to match schema is also not what I want to archive.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use DTO. Retrieving and sending entity object is bad practice as you do not want your grahql api to change every time you refactor you database model, or in your case. Your Sheep and Cow objects are DTO, but you will need some way to convert your entity to DTO (`getGraphQlCowFromCowEntity` is fine, but you could use polymorphism - `CowEntity.toDTO()` - or have a service layer do the conversion, there are plenty of way to do this).

To answer your concerns about loading only the requested data, you want your DTO object to only be populated with the requested fields. One way to do this is, instead of populating all fields, have the DTO own a reference to the entity object and retrieve the data from the entity object only when requested.

```
public class Sheep {

    private SheepE entity;
    public Sheep(SheepE entity){
        this.entity=entity;
    }

    public getId() {
        return entity.getId();
    }

    public getLastTimeSheared() {
        return entity.getLastTimeSheared();
    }
    ...
}
```

Please see this answer I wrote to a similar question: [Graphql Tools: Map entity type to graphql type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58801227/graphql-tools-map-entity-type-to-graphql-type/58809449#58809449)